# SNMP MIB design for different devices

Tags: snmp

If more than one device are sending the same trap's value with same OID, is there any way to differentiate which trap came from which device apart from IP address?

Comment: If you do rely on other identifiers, make them part of the trap message in your notification definition.

Answer (score 1):

If you are the author of the MIB, the you could simply add a dedicated var-bind  for that purpose (perhaps of type SNMPv2-SMI IpAddress).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the variable binding (informational OID) in the generated trap, which is termed as the SNMP Variable bind.

For Example: We have a case where our two same application was installed in the same machine, So when any entity got alive or down the snmp trap was generated for that, and it's hard to recognize which entity was down or alive from which server. For that we introduce our own custom OID viz. instanceIdentity which hold the identity of the server for which particular entity was down or alive. We termed it as "Advance Trap"